# timer() usage within a while loop, resetting caused by if statements in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, timer

I'm attempting to have a timer that counts down from 5 and when 0 is reached it will set a boolean value to false. The code follows:

```
def touchInput():
while inputTime < lastInputTime + 5:
    inputTable = []                 

    inputTime = timer()
    lastInputTime = timer()

    TouchSensor('in2')
    if True:
        inputTable.append(".")
        inputTime = timer()

    TouchSensor('in3')
    if True:
        inputTable.append("-")
        inputTime = timer()

    else:
        lastInputTime = timer()


inputAllowed = False
```

I'm receiving an error within the else statement saying that the variable is unreachable in PyCharm. Is there a better way to phrase this code?

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: In your conditional statements you are using True. As such it will always enter this block and that is why you are seeing the message about the else block being unreachable.

Comment: This is not my full code however my issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Both of your `if True` statements are obsolete as they aren't really conditions. You should have a variable there that may either be `True` or `False`. In the second case the `else`-case will never be reached, because the if-"condition" will always evaluate to `True`.